# How can I return specific rows where there IS a rate on the contract listed, but NO rate in the system?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset of billing information in one tab, and on the next tab, I'd like to only see the rows where there is a rate in the contract column, but no rate shown/saved in the system.

It would be like a view only tab. Ideally, I'd like it to change/react automatically to changes in the first tab.
[image: visual]

I tried using <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd> & <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> but kept getting a #value error.

Comment: If there is not a value in the "Rate on Contract" column is it zero or N/A?

Comment: It would just be 0 in the contract column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A7</kbd>

```
=VSTACK(A1:D1,FILTER(A2:D4,(D2:D4>0)*IFERROR(C2:C4,0)=0))
```

---

For `Non-MS365`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A12</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$D$4)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
  (($D$2:$D$4>0)*(IFERROR($C$2:$C$4,0)=0)),ROWS(A$12:A12)),),"")
```

---

Caveat ensure while exiting the formula to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Also, you can use this one as well.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$D$4)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
 (($D$2:$D$4>0)*(IFERROR($C$2:$C$4,0)=0)),ROWS($A$12:$A12)),MATCH(A$11,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

---

Where you need to fill right and fill down!

---

Or, you can pull the data in this way as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A7</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A1:E4,
     b,TAKE(a,1),
     c,DROP(a,1),
     d,INDEX(c,,3),
     e,INDEX(c,,4),
     DROP(VSTACK(b,FILTER(c,(e>0)*(IFERROR(d,0)=0))),,-1))
```

---

Updated:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,A1:F4,
     b,TAKE(a,1),
     c,DROP(a,1),
     d,INDEX(c,,4),
     e,INDEX(c,,5),
     f,FILTER(c,(e>0)*(IFERROR(d,0)=0)),
     DROP(VSTACK(b,IF(f=0,"",f)),,-1))
```

---

Comment: For the 1st formula, I'm amazed at your use of FILTER/IFERROR! Any idea why I'm getting an #N/A error in the cell on the next tab where I'm trying to place the formula?

Comment: Next tab, means next sheet, you need to use proper reference of the sheet and cell ranges definitely

Comment: Ok wait I see whats happening; when I'm typing in the formula and get to the "IFERROR(C2:C4,0)" part, it's not letting me set the range, it just says "...IFERROR(C2#,0)". Any idea why?

Comment: Oh okay, make it, like this way `IFERROR($C$2#,0)`

Comment: Still says "A value is not available to the formula or function" :/ thank you so much for trying for sure i'll have to try another way to display rows that dont have a rate in system but do have a rate in contract

Comment: @kodster17 see i updated in another way, look at the last answer. Well, let me post an excel, you can see on your own and verify.

Comment: @kodster17 download the file from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjn4OTyPbdh1aUFCK?e=DhHsYf)**

Comment: WOW, ok wait I made a silly mistake (and updated the visual picture), there is one more column in after event name! Please take a look and let me know if that changes any of your helpful answers:)

Comment: @kodster17 you just need to change the index number of the range. see i have updated